# How to filter 2d Model-Array in swift 4,

Tags: ios, swift4

I am doing like this:-

```
    let dataToSend = self.allOrders.filter { (ordersForOneDate) -> Bool in

            return ordersForOneDate.filter({ (myOrder) -> Bool in

                if myOrder.is_request == "1" &&
                    myOrder.order_status != "confirmed" &&
                    myOrder.order_status != "completed" {

                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
```

but getting ERROR

> Cannot convert value of type '[MyOrdersModel]' to closure result type 'Bool'

Comment: Because the internal filter will be array not bool. So, you have do `return ordersForOneDate.filter{}.count > 0`

Comment: ok mate, let me try

Comment: @kathayatnk ohh yeah got it now bro, thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter out items from you 2d array then you need to map the outer array instead of filtering it. You may also remove empty arrays. Try something like:

```
func filterMy2DArray(allOrders: [[Order]], includesEmptyArrays includeEmpty: Bool = false) -> [[Order]] {
    let dataToSend: [[Order]] = allOrders.compactMap { ordersForOneDate in
        let filtered = ordersForOneDate.filter({ myOrder in
            if myOrder.is_request == "1" &&
                myOrder.order_status != "confirmed" &&
                myOrder.order_status != "completed" {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        })
        if includeEmpty {
            return filtered
        } else {
            return filtered.isEmpty ? nil : filtered
        }
    }
    return dataToSend
}
```

So now the inner array is filtered to get items you want. It then checks (if `includeEmpty` if false) if array is empty and returns `nil` if so. What `compactMap` will do is construct array of arrays the block is providing but will ignore those that are `nil`.

Comment: @VipulKumar The solution in the question's comment will produce a very different result, so be cautious. It will not filter your internal arrays but rather remove arrays that have NO elements that correspond to your check. I ma not sure which do you need though.

Comment: yeah mate, but this time my requirement is like that,  but your answer increase my knowledge, really appreciable :)

Comment: what will be a good approach if again i want to make 1d Array instead of 2d array with this result, without FOR loop ?

Comment: @VipulKumar `let d1Array: [Order] = dataToSend.flatMap { $0 }` You could naturally use it instead of `compactMap` directly.

Comment: see i do like this for that:- let dataInOneD_Array = dataToSend.flatMap { $0 }